# Attribute Error: 'join' object has no attribute 'implicit_returning'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I've the table model:

```
class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'example'

    id = Column(ForeignKey(u'visit.id', ondelete=u'CASCADE', onupdate=u'CASCADE'), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    startdate = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    enddate = Column(Date)
```

And I try insert a new row:

```
session.begin()
i = sqlalchemy.insert(Example)
i = i.values({'id': 1, 'startdate': 1570798620, 'enddate': 1572526620})
session.execute(i)
session.commit()
```

But I get next error: `'Join' object has no attribute 'implicit_returning'`
What is this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to insert an instance of an SQLAlchemy ORM model is to create an instance of your class, then `.add()` it to the session ([ORM Tutorial reference](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#adding-and-updating-objects)):

```py
session.begin()
ex = Example(id=1, startdate=1570798620, enddate=1572526620)
session.add(ex)
session.commit()
```